# Прямая через две точки в matplotlib, помогите

Tags: python, matplotlib

Нужно провести прямую через две точки, есть код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1 = [0,1]
y1 = [-1,0]

x2 = [0,4]
y2 = [2,0]


plt.plot(x1, y1, marker='o')
plt.plot(x2, y2, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Здесь два отрезка, то есть линия заканчивается на точках, нужно через эти точки провести именно две прямых (что бы линия не заканчивалась на точках а шла дальше до конца графика)
Суть вопроса, как провести две прямых, через две точки каждую, что бы показать в каком месте будет пересечение неужели это не возможно ?